# access run time error 3075

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have this Function where i get a 3075 run time error. It is on this line of code, i will post rest afterwards.
I have a sub-form which has 3 boxes to choose either option to get back data on the form (Brand,Generic,Manufacturer). I take it something is wrong with getting back data to form with my IF statements but not sure how to rephrase it.

Error line is this in debug mode - Me.tbl_Drug_Master_Date_subform.Form.RecordSource = task

Error message states: Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression `'[Brand]=Idaloprine'And[Generic] like '*'And[Manufacturer] like '*'`

Full code:

```
Function SearchCriteria()
Dim Brandtype, strGeneric, strManufacturer
Dim task, strCriteria As String

If IsNull(Me.cboBrand) Then
    Brandtype = "[BRAND] like '*'"
Else
    Brandtype = "[BRAND] = " & Me.cboBrand & "'"
End If

If IsNull(Me.cboGeneric) Then
    strGeneric = "[Generic] like '*'"
Else
    strGeneric = "[Generic] = " & Me.cboGeneric & "'"
End If

If IsNull(Me.cboManufacturer) Then
    strManufacturer = "[MANUFACTURER] like '*'"
Else
    strManufacturer = "[MANUFACTURER] = " & Me.cboManufacturer & "'"
End If

strCriteria = Brandtype & "And" & strGeneric & "And" & strManufacturer

    task = "Select GENERIC, BRAND,   MASTER_ID, PRODUCT_CATEGORY, MANUFACTURER, HTP_MODEL_QTR, HTP_SELECTION_REASON1, LU.ID, LU.Date_YYYYQX  from [tbl_Drug_Master] DM left outer join tbl_YYYYQX_LU LU on LU.ID = DM.HTP_MODEL_QTR Where " & strCriteria
    Me.tbl_Drug_Master_Date_subform.Form.RecordSource = task
    Me.tbl_Drug_Master_Date_subform.Form.Requery

End Function
```

Comment: Make sure when you post code to check the formatting and indentation in the preview so that code is correctly formatted and has a readable indentation (yours is not formatted correctly).

Answer (score 1):

> Error message states: Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression `'[Brand]=Idaloprine'And[Generic] like '*'And[Manufacturer] like '*'`

As the message says, your query expression is broken. The single quotes `'` are used to enclose string literals. Thus, `'[Brand] = Idaloprine'` is a string literal, not a comparison. What you probably wanted to write was `[Brand] = 'Idaloprine'`. This is a comparison (`=`) between a field (`[Brand]`) and a string literal (`'Idaloprine'`).

Thus, your goal is to modify your code such that your query expression reads

```
[Brand] = 'Idaloprine' And [Generic] Like '*' And [Manufacturer] Like '*'
```

Modifying your code to achieve that is left as an exercise.

Comment: Heinzi - i am not sure what you mean. Brand, Generic and Manufacturer are fields i can choose from. So if i select 1 of them the others will get nulled out. Idaloprine is one of the Brands to choose from the combobox. I did try this code and got same error. Brandtype = "[BRAND] like '*' And [Generic] like '*' And [Manufacturer] like '*'". I tried that in all 3 If statements. was that what you were talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Two problems.  First of all, your quotes aren't matching:

```
Brandtype = "[BRAND] = " & Me.cboBrand & "'"
```

You're missing a single quote at the beginning of cboBrand.  So, if cboBrand = "Coke", what you have will produce:

```
Brandtype = "[BRAND] = Coke'"
```

Notice the missing opening single-quote?  Replace them with something like this:

```
Brandtype = "[BRAND] = '" & Me.cboBrand & "'"
```

Second problem; spacing.  Here's your code:

```
strCriteria = Brandtype & "And" & strGeneric & "And" & strManufacturer
```

You need spaces, or it will all be interpreted as one long word.  Try this:

```
strCriteria = Brandtype & " And " & strGeneric & " And " & strManufacturer
```

Comment: Johnny Bones - Thanks for the help. It partially works. The Error is gone but now when i choose one of the boxes to select data from i dont get data when i select Brand. I get data using Generic or Manufacturer. Weird.

Comment: It is now working fine. i do have to use the "Clear" button i created to choose new fields to display for Brand, Generic, Manufacturer. weird again. Thanks for the help on spacing on single quote i was missing.